Adding a single line to fstab creates two pairs of duplicate devices in Thunar side pane (and may have other side effects)
Brief background: My multi-TB zfs array is mounted at root level (/bertha). I've got some apps (Steam, Plex) that refuse to believe that /bertha is a reasonable place to put files (I'm sure they're right, but it's too late now), so I can't get them to access any files that are there.
So I created a ~/bertha directory and bound it to /bertha with sudo mount --bind /bertha/ ~/bertha/, and Steam was happy.  (I tried soft and hard links first, but Steam wasn't fooled.)
So with that working, I just needed to add this line to my fstab to restore the bind after every reboot:
/bertha /home/fred/bertha none bind

And that works too.  But now the left panel of Thunar shows:

Computer
fred
Recent
Trash
Filesystem
239 GB Volume (clicking gives the error message below - could be a clue)
bertha
bertha (both "berthas" point to the same place; i.e. appear to be identical)
Network

Error message when clicking on "239 GB Volume":
Failed to mount "239 GB Volume"
Device /dev/sda2 is already mounted at '/', '/home/fred/bertha', '/var/'.

Before adding the bind line to fstab, the left panel of Thunar showed:

Computer
fred
Recent
Trash
Filesystem
Network

Not even one bertha, and no "239 GB Volume".
Full fstab (last line is the one in question):
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/disk/by-uuid/fe937601-0ff9-4359-94b6-604cd5e7d57a / ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/81CE-88A2 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1

# backup drive
UUID=bf79b05a-9b9c-4ed0-bf53-a9e85d01a52c /backup ext4 defaults 0 2

/bertha /home/fred/bertha none bind

If this is only a cosmetic issue (I now have 3 new entries in my Thunar side panel), I can live with it.  But it's strange enough that I thought it was worth looking into.
Update: Asked ChatGPT4 and it suggested hiding the mount with
 /bertha /home/fred/bertha none bind,x-gvfs-hide 0 0

and one of the berthas disappeared...now if I can just lose the "239 GB Volume"...

I used to have similar problems back in the 12.04 days with unwanted partitions showing up in the file manager. I hid them with udev rules. It looks like that can still be done but not the way I did it back then https://superuser.com/a/695817/471860

This looks a lot like Ubuntu 20.04 file browser showing all zfs mounts explicitly in side-panel which links to this discussion No way to remove zfs mounts from sidebar when mounts occur in user Home folder

@steeldriver At this point I just want to get rid of the '239 GB Volume', which weirdly is ext4, not zfs.

Does changing mount option defaults to defaults,x-gvfs-hide have any effect?
